# Return not working and overcomplex code

Tags: javascript

As part of a bigger function, I'm trying to simply run a check to see whether the values in an array are 'increasing' - e.g.:

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5] // is increasing
var a = [1,4,6,7,36] // is increasing
var a = [1,6,3,6,5] // not increasing
```

It's increasing if the previous value a[previous] is less than a[next]. For some reason, the problem is it doesn't return -1 when it's not increasing. And, as I'm learning JavaScript, my code seems way more complex than it should be.

My Questions:
1. why does it not return -1 when a cannot increase?
2. why is my code seemingly so complex for such a simple test? am I missing something? (that is, if you think it's overcomplex, which often my code is)

What would be a better way of writing such a function? Should I put the 'test if already increased' part inside a separate function? If someone could also give hints about writing better, simpler, readable, drier code, that would be much appreciated :)

```js
var a = [1,2,3,4,5]
var canIncrease = 0; // boolean

// test if already increased
for(i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
 if((a[i] < a[i+1] && i !== a.length-1)||(a[i] > a[i-1] && i==a.length-1)) {
  console.log('index ' + i + ' cannot increase');
 } else {
  console.log('index ' + i + ' can increase');
  canIncrease = 1;
 }
}

if (!canIncrease) {
 console.log('array a cannot increase');
 return -1;
} else {
 console.log('would continue');
 // continue with main function...
}
```

Comment: `return` is only meaningful inside a function definition.

Comment: `0` and `1` are not booleans

Comment: If the last element of your array can increase, `canIncrease` will be set to 1 whether or not the other elements can increase. Is this what you want?

Comment: It looks like you call return outside of the function, post your entire code so we can see the scope of it.

Comment: You need to swap the order of `a[i] < a[i+1] && i !== a.length-1`. `&&` is evaluated from left to right, and you need to test that `i+1` is in range *before* trying to use `a[i+1]`. You can also simply change the `for` header to use `i < a.length-1`.

Comment: @Andreas, true, but in the context it is used (as a condition to an `if`) it works.

Comment: It's still better style to use real booleans.

Comment: @Barmar no doubt about that

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca This doesn't make it any better. With this explanation I could also write `canIncrease = ""; /* ... */ canIncrease = "yeah it can really increase";`

Comment: @Andreas I do agree, but I read your comment to imply that was the problem with the code. I think I misread.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I think he was just commenting on the comment in the code: `var canIncrease = 0; // boolean`

Comment: What do you want to happen with this? var a = [2,1,2,3] In other words: does the whole list needs to increase or only in the end? Because not all solutions offered here give you the same meaning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `every()` and return true if the element is the last element OR smaller than the next element.

```js
function func(arr) {
  return arr.every((o, i, a) => (i + 1) === a.length ||  o < a[i + 1] );
}

console.log(func([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
console.log(func([1, 4, 6, 7, 36]));
console.log(func([1, 6, 3, 6, 5]));
```

Doc: [every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Comment: +1, I guess it's best to use [`.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) here. Works great.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method to achieve the desired result:

> The [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method applies a function against an accumulator and each element in the array (from left to right) to reduce it to a single value.

- on every element compare the current element `curr` with the saved one `acc`. If the current is greater and not `false` save it in `acc` for the next element. Else set `acc` to `false`.
- At the end, if the array is in ascending `acc` will be an integer (the last element in the array, i.e. the maximum). Else `acc` will be `false`.
- adding `!!` before the statement ensures the integers are converted to bools.

So the statement will look like:

```
!!a.reduce((acc, curr) => (acc && (curr >= acc)) ? curr : false)
```

---

ES6 syntax:

- `() => {}` or `() =>` are shorthand syntax to define functions ([arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions))
- `condition ? expr1 : expr2` is a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), it's equivalent to `if(condition) { expr1 } else { expr2 }`

---

Here are some tests:

```js
const isAscOrder = (a) => !!a.reduce((acc, curr) => (acc && (curr >= acc)) ? curr : false);


console.log(
  isAscOrder([2, 2, 3, 4, 5]) // is increasing
);

console.log(
  isAscOrder([1, 6, 3, 6, 5]) // is not increasing
);


console.log(
  isAscOrder([2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) // is not increasing
);
```

---

I've just noticed the previous function didn't work if the array contained a `0`: for example: `[0, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. The reason being that `0` is `false`. In order to solve this, we can use `NaN` instead of `false`:

```
!isNaN(a.reduce((acc, curr) => (!isNaN(acc) && (curr >= acc)) ? curr : NaN))
```

```js
const isAscOrder = (a) => !isNaN(a.reduce((acc, curr) => (!isNaN(acc) && (curr >= acc)) ? curr : NaN));


console.log(
  isAscOrder([0, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5]) // is increasing
);

console.log(
  isAscOrder([1, 6, 3, 6, 5]) // is not increasing
);


console.log(
  isAscOrder([2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) // is not increasing
);
```

Comment: depending on the meaning behind the question this answer can have an issue. Try: [2,1,2,3,4,5]

Answer (score 1):

To answer your last question, this can be simplified to the following:

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5]
var b = [1,4,6,7,36]
var c = [1,6,3,6,5]

function isIncreasing(arr) {
    return arr.every((n, i) => i === 0 || n[i - 1] < n);
}

isIncreasing(a); //true
isIncreasing(b); //true
isIncreasing(c); //false
```